# release memory of returned values/pointers to CvMat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have got a problem to release memory with OpenCV. 
How can I release memory of a returned pointer?

Here is my code:

This is the function where I a call the function thinning:

```
int preprocessing_and_classification() { 

/// Section 2D - Perform morphological processing 

            CvMat* image1_edge_morpho = thinning(image1_edge); 
                        ....... 
                        ....... 
                        ........... 

                        //////////////// release the memory /////////////// 
            cvReleaseImage(&img); 
            cvReleaseMat(&image1); 
            cvReleaseMat(&image1_edge); 
            cvReleaseMat(&image1_edge_morpho); 
            cvReleaseImage(&imgg); 
            cvReleaseImage(&imggT); 
            cvReleaseMemStorage(&g_storage); 
            cvReleaseMat(&features); 
            cvReleaseMat(&labels_obtained); 
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
return num_bacilli; 

}
```

The function thinning which you can see below returns the Pointer Merode:

```
CvMat* thinning(CvMat* M){ 

/* 
Input parameters 
CvMat* M = Pointer to the matrix on which morphological processing needs to be done. 

Output parameters 
CvMat* Merode = Pointer to morphological processed matrix. 
*/ 



    CvMat* Merode = cvCreateMat(h,w,CV_8UC1); 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    . 



    ///// Releasing the images, matrices and structuring elements to free memroy. 
   // Matrix Merode is not released as it is the output of this function file 
    cvReleaseStructuringElement(&B); 
    cvReleaseMat( &Mopen ); 
    cvReleaseMat( &temp ); 
    cvReleaseMat( &Mclose ); 
    cvReleaseMat( &temp1 ); 
    cvReleaseMat( &MM ); 
    cvReleaseImage( &img1 ); 
    cvReleaseMemStorage(&g_storage); 
    cvReleaseMat( &Mimg1 ); 
    cvReleaseMat( &Mimg2 ); 


    return Merode; 
}
```

How can I delete Merode?

Comment: You could use `cv::Mat` from the C++ interface and forget all about memory management.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The problem is, I didn't write all functions of the software by myseld so I don't want to change too much. 1) Can you tell me how I can delete the returned value ? 2) What would I have to change in the source code to use your mentioned C++ interface ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to change the `thinning` function you can use [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#mat) or [`cv::Ptr<cvMat>`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#ptr) (or even `std::unieue_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` with custom deleters - in case of c++11 compatible compiler)

If you're not allowed to change the code, you should delete the returning pointer wherever you're using the method. the easiest way is to wrap the pointer with `cv::Ptr<>`.

Comment: Hey Mohammad, thanks for your reply. Could you exactly how I can deltet the returning pointer in the calling function  preprocessing_and_classification() ?

Comment: In your example you're actually releasing the returning pointers memory `cvReleaseMat(&image1_edge_morpho)` but if you want to replace it with a smart pointer you can remove the release part and replace the first line with this `cv::Ptr<cvMat> image1_edge_morpho = cv::Ptr<cvMat>(thinning(image1_edge))`